# Memory leak in JavaScript (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I'm calling a function 50 times a second, which does some expensive things as it is painting alot on a `<canvas>` element.

It works great, no problems there, but I just took a look at the memory usage and it was stealing 1MB a second of my RAM. Chrome seems to garbage collect, as it went down each minute or so, but then the usage grew again.

What I tried is putting `return` at certain places in my function so as to decide what part of my function exactly causes the leak. I've been able to cut it down to a specific line of code, after which the evil part comes, but I don't really know how to solve it.

My questions are:

- What tool is available to effectively measure JavaScript memory leaks in Chrome?
- Would it be effective to set variables to `null` / `undefined` after they have been used, something like disposing them?

If the source code is really necessary I wouldn't hestitate to post it here, but I must admit that it's both long and perhaps a little ununderstandable for others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just going to pull this quote directly, linked from the article;

> Speaking of memory leaks, breaking circular references — the cause of the leaks — is usually done with simple null assignment. There’s usually no need to use delete. Moreover, null‘ing allows to “dereference” variables — what delete would normally not be able to do.

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
// circular reference is formed
el.onclick = function() { /* ... */ };
// circular reference is broken
el = null;
// can't `delete el` in this case, as `el` has DontDelete
```

> For these reasons, it’s best to stick with null‘ing when breaking circular references.

[**delete** Explained](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: Actually, I do not have circular references. It's all custom `Vector` classes which represent points in 3D and 2D in my renderer function. I guess they're accumulating in memory if I call the function 50 times a second. Will null'ing still help? I've been experimenting to no avail at the moment, both using `delete` and `= null`.

Comment: @pimvdb Read the article, it is quite long but very thorough in showing how delete actually works. I couldn't say whether either option would be successful for you. js leaks are always a b**ch.

Answer (score 3):

Look at heap profile under the Profiles tab in Chrome's developer tools for information about memory usage.

You can do the following to prevent memory leaks:

- Test your code with [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), to see if that will give you some pointers.
- Use the `var` keyword to give your variables function scope, so they can be garbage collected when they go out of scope. Without the `var` keyword variables have global scope.
- Use `delete variable;` statements to remove the object as well as the reference from memory. Setting the variable to null will only remove the object from memory, but not its reference.

Comment: Thanks. Do you perhaps know whether the for loop variable (e.g. `i`) will automatically get disposed after the for loop has ended?

Comment: @pimvdb: it will not, since only functions define scope in javascript. Read more about the javascript scope here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting